# Bounded-width Konig's lemma in reverse math

Tags: lo.logic, reverse-math

We define $\mathsf{BWKL}$ as follows:
Every infinite binary tree of bounded width has an infinite path.

This obviously follows from $\mathsf{WKL}$. Is this principle true in $\mathsf{RCA}_0$? If not, what does it need?

I've found [a paper](https://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~lak/buchi_strength.pdf) that addresses a related principle by the same name and shows it follows from $\mathsf{I\Sigma}^0_2$ ($\Sigma^0_2$-induction)... but it appears to assume that the tree has finite width, not merely bounded. (Also, I don't think it gives any lower bound on the principle's strength.)

---

EDIT: After some off-site discussion with Prof. Kołodziejczyk (one of the authors of this paper), I'd like to correct two minor confusions on my part. The bounded-width Konig's lemma discussed by Kołodziejczyk, Michalewski, Pradic, and Skrzypczak is precisely what I was asking about (which appears in Simpson & Yokoyama's work, as mentioned in Denis Hirschfeldt's answer). This is already pointed out in the journal version of the paper, though not in the preprint I'd linked. On the other hand, it is true that the paper does not address lower bounds, so it did not already answer my question.

Also: of course the distinction I was drawing between finite & bounded does not apply in this context; since we're talking about sets IN the model, it's straightforward to see that every bounded set (with maximum less than some first-order object) is finite (in the sense of having a canonical index). My only excuse: I always get bogged down in the details of first-order concerns, so I erred on the overly-cautious side.

Comment: What do _you_ mean by "bounded width"?

Comment: If the issue is that some levels of the tree may be smaller than others, if still below the uniform bound, then can't we simply generate another tree, with the same infinite paths, simply by padding with nodes so as to bring every level up to uniform size?

Comment: I highlighted the finite/bounded distinction because of the concern that we may deal with models with nonstandard first-order part; thus, finite [in the sense of having a canonical index] and bounded can sometimes fail to coincide. Essentially, I was hedging my bets in case a first-order issue was going to become suddenly relevant.

For what it's worth, I meant precisely WKL(w-bd) as mentioned in Yokoyama's talk... which is linked from Denis's answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this principle is indeed provable from either WKL or I$\Sigma^0_2$, but not in RCA$_0$, or even WWKL$_0$. See slides 12 and 13 in [this talk](https://www.birs.ca/cmo-workshops/2016/16w5072/files/Yokoyama.pdf) by Yokoyama. Based on [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.00931.pdf) by Nies, Triplett, and Yokoyama, it seems that these results will appear in a paper by Simpson and Yokoyama. It is interesting that, as noted in both these links, if we bound the size of prefix-free sets rather than just that of levels, the principle becomes provable in RCA$_0$.

Comment: Pray tell, kind sir, what is WWKL?

Comment: @Asaf Karagila WWKL (Weak Weak Konig's Lemma) is the statement that if $T$ is a binary tree such that $\liminf_n \frac{T \cap 2^n}{2^n} > 0$ then $T$ has an infinite path. It comes up particularly in the reverse mathematics of measure theory, and is equivalent over RCA$_0$ to the statement that for any $X$, there is a set that is Martin-Lof random relative to $X$.

Comment: Very nice - I'll have to watch for this forthcoming paper! I'll also have to see if I can bound the size of the prefix-free set where I'd been hoping to use the result.